# How to perform a query based on the result set of another query on the same table?

Tags: mysql

Requests can be made for multiple items and the only key is the surrogate request_id

I have the following query which returns a result set of 9 digit phone numbers

```
SELECT phone_number FROM purchases
WHERE item_type = 'popcorn'
GROUP BY phone_number;
```

I would like to then retrieve a list of of every `DISTINCT` `item_type` requested by each of those `phone_number` that was not 'popcorn' and then `GROUP BY` that `item_type`.  IE I want to know what similar products customers tend to buy.

The desired result set may look something like this

```
item        COUNT(*)
pretzels    200
chips       150
crackers    125
…           …
```

In this case the number of `phone_number`'s who bought popcorn and pretzels was 200 (I'm interested in this value).  The total number of purchase of pretzels by people who bought popcorn was 1,000 but this is not the value I am interested in.

How can I create a single query that only specifies the `item_type` and retrieves a result like the above which shows items customers also bought?

Also - If someone can help me make a more descript title that would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

Here is the table

```
CREATE TABLE purchases(
    request_id BIGINT NOT NULL auto_increment,
    phone_number INT(9) NOT NULL,
    item_type VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(request_id)
);
```

**EDIT**

Request for desired output based on this data http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/23236/2

```
item        COUNT(*)
cc          1
notpopcorn  1
```

Comment: Can you please post the tables' structures?

Comment: Sure - there's only one table but give me 2 min

Comment: phone numbers are not integers...

Comment: I simplified it for sake of this example, I'm not using a phone number but some other identifier.  For this particular example I should have used `phone_number INT(9) UNSIGNED NOT NULL`.  Also all customers are in the USA where most phone numbers are 9 digits long

Comment: Wow - where is my head, I meant to say most phone numbers are 10 digits long... sorry

Comment: "`that` was not 'popcorn'" What you mean by `that` here? `item_type` or `phone_numbers`? `Phone number` was never popcorn, so it should mean `item_type`. Right? Please carefully watch for sentence structure here

Comment: I would like to then retrieve a list of of every `DISTINCT` `item_type` requested by each of those `phone_number` that was not 'popcorn'.  So "that" means  `DISTINCT` `item_type` requested by each of those `phone_number`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to then retrieve a list of of every DISTINCT item_type
>   requested by each of those phone_number that was not 'popcorn' and
>   then GROUP BY that item_type. IE I want to know what similar products
>   customers tend to buy.

Try this:

```
SELECT item_type as item, COUNT(*)
FROM purchases 
WHERE phone_number NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT phone_number 
                           FROM purchases
                           WHERE item_type = 'popcorn')
GROUP BY item_type;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/98466/1)

**Update:** Try this:

```
SELECT item_type as item, COUNT(*)
FROM purchases 
GROUP BY item_type, phone_number
HAVING phone_number IN (SELECT DISTINCT phone_number 
                           FROM purchases
                           WHERE item_type = 'popcorn')
  AND item_type <> 'popcorn';
```

### [Updated SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/23236/7)

Comment: Hmm I don't think this is what I am looking for.  In your example the two numbers that bought popcorn are `54545` and `44444`.  Those numbers did not buy anything else, therefore the result set would be `null` `null` for `item` and `COUNT(*)`

Comment: @user784637 - So, what is the desired output in this: [**Sample data**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/23236/2)

Comment: Thanks for the follow up - see my edit to OP.  This is because number `55` also bought `cc` and number `44` also bought `notpopcorn` in addition to `popcorn`.  I'm no mysql expert but I think a part of the problem is the `NOT IN` statement, it should be `IN`.  This query is running is extremely slow though, would I need to reindex my table?  It has about 350k records.

Comment: @user784637 - Sorry, I can't get that. Why `cc` `item_type` should have `COUNT(*) = 1` whereas it has two entries. Shouldn't be 2 for it. Here is my attempt: [**Updated SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/23236/7). Like in My updated answer/ Thanks

Comment: Thanks again for the follow up.  So in my OP I wrote _In this case the number of phone_number's who bought popcorn and pretzels was 200 (I'm interested in this value). The total number of purchase of pretzels by people who bought popcorn was 1,000 but this is not the value I am interested in._  I want the `DISTINCT` `item_type` per `phone_number`, then I want to aggregate all of those for each `phone_number` and `GROUP BY` the `item_type`.  Did I explain that okay?  If someone buys thousands of the same item, I just want to count 1 purchase of it.

Comment: The query `SELECT DISTINCT phone_number 
                           FROM purchases
                           WHERE item_type = 'popcorn'` takes about .75 seconds to execute and returns a result set of about 50 phone numbers.  However when I execute the entire query, the query hangs infinitely.  Is there a way I can get the intended result set without using a nested query?  It seems to be slow

Comment: @user784637 - Firstly is this what you are looking for? Try to add an index to `phone_number`. I can't think of an alternative solution that a subquery. Try to add an index.

Comment: This is close to what I'm looking for.  However in the most recent example, you're counting the total amount of purchase of an item per `phone_number`.  For example `phone_number` 55 purchased 'cc' two times however the desired functionality is for a maximum of 1 per person.  For example I want to count the **total amount of people** who have gone to Hawaii *NOT* the **total amount of visits** made to Hawaii (ex someone can visit hawaii numerous times).